# not well formed error on first line in xpi

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpi

In my XPI I am fetching javascript code from the user's PC (file://) and run the js code in sandbox.
For some reason I get not well formed error on the first line of my code which is a comment:

> // Yosy

My code is still running but this error is annoying and I want to fix this, any suggestions?

**Code Example for running the code:**

```
var sandbox = new Components.utils.Sandbox(safeWin); 
sandbox.window = win;
sandbox.doc = win.doc;
sandbox.__proto__ = win;
```

Comment: How are you initializing the sandbox? Are you using `Components.utils.Sandbox`? Could we maybe see a snippet of the critical code?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with sandbox usage code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not well-formed" is an XML processing error. Somewhere the browser attempts to interpret your JavaScript code as XML. Your code example doesn't show it but I *guess* that you are using `XMLHttpRequest` to download your script - and by default `XMLHttpRequest` will attempt to parse the XML code (as it name already says). You want to tell it that you are downloading plain text that should not be parsed:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url);
request.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
request.send();
```

Comment: Thanks Wladimir, for some reason I get "syntax error". do you have reason why? btw - I added the overrideMimeType with "text/javascript"

Comment: @Yosy: There is always a file and line number mentioned for each error - don't hesitate to check where the error happens ;). `text/plain` or `text/javascript` doesn't matter, as long as it isn't something with XML.